# log every command on linux server

Tags: linux, syslog

I have a snoopy logger on my linux server. It works perfect, but when I use midnight commander I dont see commands that I made there.
In logs only 'mc' and no functional keys.
So is there any way to log it?

Comment: Have you tried installing a keylogger? If a program doesn't want to provide any logs it's going to be hard to log commands made in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to be useful. Pressing function keys in Midnight commander doesn't result in shell commands but in direct library and subsequent kernel calls to modify the file system. Logging on this level will be overwhelming and not useable (run mc in strace to see what I mean).

If what you want to track is who modified which file and when, look into the Linux auditing subsystem.